# while loop less than symbol '<' raising error in Ruby (RubyMine)

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I am adding all numbers that are multiples of 3 and 5 less-than 1000.

This is my error:

```
in `multiple_sum': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Here is my code:

```
def multiple_sum(n)
  five_total, three_total, three_subtract = 0
  while five_total < n
    five_total += five_total+5
  end
  while three_total < n
    if (three_total+3)%5 == 0
      three_subtract += three_total+3
    end
    three_total += three_total+3
  end
  puts (three_total-three_subtract) + five_total
end

multiple_sum(1000)
```

Is there a problem with my `while` loop condition?

Comment: While your "bug" has been fixed, this code doesn't actually do what you say. If you call `multiple_sum(11)` it returns 36, but it should have added the numbers 3+6+9+5+10=33 (if you mean "multiples of 3 and multiples of 5" - or it should have been 0 if you meant multiples of both 5 and 3), `multiple_sum(3)` returns 8! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for chained assignment: `five_total = three_total = three_subtract = 0`.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. You are just not setting a value for all the variables listed:

```
five_total, three_total, three_subtract = 0
```

That code assigns zero to the first variable, `five_total` only. `three_total` and `three_subtract` are set to `nil`.

You should set them too:

```
five_total, three_total, three_subtract = 0, 0, 0
```